# Chrome crashes while using ng-repeat with limitTo on a large number of values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a dictionary and I want to show the first 20 values. 
This is how the code currently looks like:

```
<div ng-repeat="b in data | limitTo:maxDisplayTerms as result">
    <span>{{::b.key | fornatValue:attribute.VALUE_TYPE}}</span>
    <span>{{::b.doc_count | number:0}}</span>
</div>
```

Up until now it worked fine but now that there are more values (about 20,000) chrome crashes every time I load the list.

What can I do to stop it from crashing?

Comment: Use `pagination`

Comment: Most of the pagination examples I saw use limitTo as well. Can you give me an example? Also, I only care about the top result I don't really need more pages